# How to execute a code random times and count it?

Tags: java, random, int

I need to execute a code random times and then count how many times I executed it.

```
  for ( int i =0; i< Math.random()*5+1; i++) {
                int X = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
                int Y = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
```

What I want to do is execute the X,Y values 1 to 5 random times.I put the code above inside a timer method so that this code will run for 5 seconds and execute my for loop for 5 seconds. And it will create random X,Y values every second for 5 seconds. But I also want to randomise x and y for Z times. They could be randomised for 5 times,2 times... every second for 5 seconds. I tried to randomise it with the code above but when I do that I cannot count how many times I got random X,Y results. My question is how can I count the number of times I randomised X and Y values?

Comment: You need to move your Math.random out of the conditional portion of your loop, it generates a new value each time.

Comment: I have read it twice and it is still confusing. What is definitely not working is the part where you `put the code above inside a timer method so that this code will run for 5 seconds and execute my for loop for 5 seconds` - if we talk about the same timer, then your code is **called** every five minutes. It does not necessarily loop for five minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
int limit = Math.random()*5+1;
for (int i =0; i< limit; i++) {
    int X = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
    int Y = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
```

The condition part in the for loop is computed for every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try just storing the random number you generate:

```java
int numberOfTimesToRandomize = (int) Math.random()*5 + 1;
for(int i =0; i <= numberOfTimesToRandomize; i++) {
    int X = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
    int Y = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple count variable after the `Math.random()` call.

For example sth like that:

```
int counter_x = 0;
int counter_y = 0;
for ( int i =0; i< Math.random()*5+1; i++) {
  int X = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
  counter_x++;
  int Y = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
  counter_y++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global j=0 variable out of timer and do like this:

```
{
  for ( int i =0; i< Math.random()*5+1; i++) {
                int X = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
                int Y = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
       }
  j = j + i;
}
```

j is number of times you randomised X and Y

Comment: This kinda worked but this shows how many times my code randomised for every turn. What I want to do is for example I run my code for 5 seconds and I got these results for j = 1,2,4,4,6. I got 5 randomed values for j which means number of times I randomised X and Y but I want the result of j = 1+2+4+4+6 = 17.

Comment: Put code below when timer stopped. Make sure j is now an array not a variable anymore.
for (k=0; k < j_Count; k++) { result=result + j[k] }

Comment: I couldn't understand the code you wrote. What is j_Count ? I created an array for J.  int[] j; j = new int[10]; then added your for loop. Then what should I do? @Minh

Comment: Because Result j = 1+2+4+4+6 = 17 that mean you must store j in array so that after timer finished you can SUM j array to get Result

Comment: Thanks but what about j_Count? Could you write the code more specific?

Comment: j_Count = Max of array for ex above j_Count = 5 {1,2,4,4,6}